# Unable to connect more than 1 client to the same server via ssh with priv/pub key pair. Only first client can login w/out password

Tags: linux, ssh, public-key-encryption, ssh-keys, sshfs

I setup a client linux computer to connect to a linux server via ssh/sshfs with a priv/pub key pair so it wouldn't require a password. I used this method:

http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

1. On client, create priv/pub key pair using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
2. Create `.ssh` directory on server: `ssh user@192.168.1.111` mkdir -p .ssh
3. Add public key to server's authorized keys: `cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@192.168.1.111 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'`

This works. BUT, when I try either of the following methods on another computer, they both fail (**Note: I tried this on two other computers and both failed**):

1. Create a new priv/pub key pair on this second computer and just like on first computer, export the pub key to the server **(This fails)**
2. Copy the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` to the `.ssh` directory on the new client computer and use that **(this also fails)**

On both the 2nd and 3rd client it keeps asking for the remote user's password (not the password for the key file). I've now tried this on 3 different computers, and it only works on the first client I set up. No others work. Why would the server only accept the first one?

Looking in the logs, I see the following difference in the successful client and a rejected client:

```
//Rejected
/var/log/audit/audit.log:type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1394819951.391:76): user pid=1787 uid=0 auid=4295967295 ses=4295967295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:d0.c1023 msg='op=pubkey acct="myuser" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=192.168.1.138 terminal=ssh res=failed'

//Successful
/var/log/audit/audit.log:type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1394821121.443:114): user pid=1865 uid=0 auid=4395767295 ses=4395767295 subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:d0.c1023 msg='op=pubkey_auth rport=56096 acct="myuser" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=192.168.1.125 terminal=? res=success'
```

The difference is the successful one has `rport=56096` and the other has no "rport".

Comment: From the first client computer in which the key copying succeeded, were you able to login to the server without the password? When you try to copy keys from other client machines, what error do u get? What is the error message in server side?

Comment: @clement89 Yes, the first client connects without password. There is no error on the client. It simply asks for the password.

Comment: Ya that is the intended behaviour. When you are trying to copy the new public key from second machine to the server, it should prompt for the password. And if you copy the same `id_rsa`,`id_rsa.pub` from first machine to the third machine, you should be able to login.

Comment: @clement89 I know I should be able to but it's not working. how do I find out why?